# How to create Facebook style fixed Status bar?

Tags: css, layout

I want to create fixed status bar in by web form to display various status/messages/notification to user , i can used fixed CSS property but i want to implement in i.e 6/7 and in Firefox. and all the browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dean Edwards' ["IE7" JavaScript library](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) may help.  It fixes position: fixed in IE6.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick and easy solution on how to fix element/bar on the bottom page:

[jixedbar - Fixed bottom bar like Facebook](http://jixedbar.rawswift.com/)

Now all you have to do next is to find an AJAX framework (prototype, jquery, etc) and start coding your custom menu (application, notification, slider, etc.) or similar to the one in Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Comment: That's not the same thing. On a long page, that footer will not display until you scroll to the footer of the page..

Answer (score 2):

There are several out there. For instance, take a look at the tickbar, which seems quite configurable: http://www.ticketmy.com/bumpin/socialbar/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple [notification bar](http://www.hellobar.com/solo/)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's a quick and dirty way to save the state of something in that bar across a site...

Answer (score -1):

view this post [Facebook Style Footer Admin Panel](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/)