# Fixed Bar like facebook/wibiya with jquery/YUI/prototype

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, yui, scriptaculous

I was just wondering if any one knows of a good script to emulate a bar like wibiya or the facebook notification bar that used to appear at the bottom(just before the current facebook homepage change) . I just checked out one of the scripts but it is still under heavy development so looking for some stabler options:

http://code.google.com/p/jixedbar/

The demo for jixedbar is at:

http://ryan.rawswift.com/

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Facebook style fixed Status bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393736/how-to-create-facebook-style-fixed-status-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tutorial for exactly what you want here ([part 1](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-2/))

**UPDATE**: BOTH LINKS ARE NOW DEAD! :(